# Amazon MWS API - SubmitFeed completed but quantity not updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I need to update quantity for a single product via SubmitFeed API and "_POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_" feed type:

```
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
        <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=""amznenvelope.xsd"">
            <Header>
                <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
                <MerchantIdentifier>MERCHANT_ID</MerchantIdentifier>
            </Header>
            <MessageType>Inventory</MessageType>
            <Message>
                <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
                <Inventory>
                    <SKU>MY_SKU_CODE</SKU>
                    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
                </Inventory>
            </Message>
        </AmazonEnvelope>
```

Submission was OK (checked from MWS Scratchpad):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>...</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>ProcessingReport</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <ProcessingReport>
            <DocumentTransactionID>...</DocumentTransactionID>
            <StatusCode>Complete</StatusCode>
            <ProcessingSummary>
                <MessagesProcessed>1</MessagesProcessed>
                <MessagesSuccessful>1</MessagesSuccessful>
                <MessagesWithError>0</MessagesWithError>
                <MessagesWithWarning>0</MessagesWithWarning>
            </ProcessingSummary>
        </ProcessingReport>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

but the quantity for that SKU hadn't changed in my inventory (as seen in my Amazon Seller Central back office). Amazon's forums did not help. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

When I run into issues where the SKU isn't updating, I include the ASIN which usually does the trick. You'd include it like this:

```
<SKU>MY_SKU</SKU>
<StandardProductID>
     <Type>ASIN</Type>
     <Value>MY_SKU'S_ASIN</Value>
</StandardProductID>
```

You can also use GCID, UPC, etc, just by changing the type in the Type field. This usually does the trick for me if fields aren't updating properly

Answer (score 0):

I find the feeds api will sometimes silently fail. See my post here for more information.

https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=347480&tstart=0

My solution (in my case tracking on orders is what I'm trying to update) is to periodically confirm that the action I took actually resulted in the change, and if the change did not happen, to just resend the feed exactly the same.